# Does scala closure feature help Apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, closures

I was having a discussion with a colleague the other day and he casually mentioned that other than in-memory computation, closure in Scala is the reason why executing applications on Spark is so efficient. I did find the below text in the official spark docs, but didn't quite understand.

> To execute jobs, Spark breaks up the processing of RDD operations into tasks, each of which is executed by an executor. Prior to execution, Spark computes the task’s closure. The closure is those variables and methods which must be visible for the executor to perform its computations on the RDD (in this case `foreach()`). This closure is serialized and sent to each executor.

Any help (pointing to other weblinks, explanation, any references) is highly valued.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind "calculating the task closure" and sending it to each executor is one of the premises of big data that it is faster/easier to send computation to where the data is rather than ship the data to the computation

Comment: Thanks Arnon. Also, about the statement "The closure is those variables and methods which must be visible for the executor to perform its computations on the RDD". Does it refer to the concept of closures in FP/Scala?

Comment: I got the answer! Adding it here just for reference.                            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015547/how-does-spark-send-closures-to-workers?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR** No. Performance and closure serialization are orthogonal.

The primary advantage of ability to compute and serialize closure (hardly Scala specific feature), is that it enables streamlined programming experience, especially in the interactive mode.

Nonetheless system like Spark could be easily developed without such feature without imposing any performance penalty. A caveat would be that user would have to explicitly state dependencies of each task. There are many examples of project which use such model with good results.

Comment: @user10976582 The closure mentioned in the spark docs doesn't relate to closures in Scala. Am i correct?